# Не выполняется INSERT запрос в mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

В базе данных имеется таблица users, в ней присутствуют поля login (VARCHAR) и id (INT, AUTO INCREMENT)
Я подключаюсь к базе данных (подключение успешно) после чего хочу добавить новую запись, но возникает ошибка, и новая запись не добавляется.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "db1634512345", "mypassword");

if ($link == false)
{
echo "Не удалось подключиться к базе данных";
}
else 
{
echo "Подключение установлено</br>";
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET login = "Андрей"';

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if ($result == false) 
{
print("Произошла ошибка при выполнении запроса");
}
  
?>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Для начала надо ввключить отображение ошибок и посмотреть что говорят и действовать опираясь на ошибку

Comment: INSERT INTO users (login) values ("Андрей")

Answer (score -3):

Необходимо было выбрать базу данных, о чём не было сказано на сайте, на котором я получил информацию:

mysql_select_db('db1634512345');

Comment: $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'baze', 'pass', 'testtable');